# How to check a column doesn't contain null values in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark streaming for reading from a source. I am trying to write a function which checks whether a given column contains null values or not. I have tried this:

```
boolean checkColumnNotNull(SparkSession spark,Dataset<Row>dataframe,String colName) throws InvalidColumnNameException {
        if(!checkColumnExists(dataframe,colName)){
            throw new InvalidColumnNameException ("column doesn't exist");
        }
        Dataset<Row> containingNulls = dataframe.where(dataframe.col(colName).isNull());
        Row[] helper = (Row[]) containingNulls.take(1);
        if(helper[0]==null){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

However, when I run this code, I get an error saying -

```
Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
```

on this line

```
Row[] helper = (Row[]) containingNulls.take(1);
```

So, according to the error , we can't use the take() function on a streaming dataframe. I tried various other ways such as count(),isEmpty() etc, but it seems that all these functions work with batch processing.

So, is there any way to perform the above operations on a streaming dataframe. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Spark Streaming, operations like take(), count(), and isEmpty() are not supported on streaming DataFrames. This is because streaming DataFrames are continuously updated with new data, and the result of these operations would be constantly changing.

Use isEmpty instead and no need to create the helper var:

```java
Dataset<Row> containingNulls = dataframe.filter(dataframe.col(colName).isNull());
return containingNulls.isStreaming() && containingNulls.isEmpty();
```

If it is streaming and empty, it means that no rows with null values in the specified column were found.

Comment: return containingNulls.isStreaming() && containingNulls.isEmpty(); How will isEmpty() work in this case ? I ran the code and it gives the same error as earlier

Comment: You said "Use isEmpty instead and no need to create the helper var". Did u mean any other function ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. spark's foreachBatch function allows us to process streaming data into batches and Inside those batches we can use functions such as count(),isEmpty() which are applicable on non streaming data.